# SSL/TLS communication in connected embedded (IoT) device

Tags: tls, key-management

while establishing the SSL/TLS based communication in an embedded device, is it necessary that device needs to acquire the keys/certificates from a CA? I read that there is also provision for device to create and use its own key!

What are the possible options and safety level associated with each option?

Comment: This question is too broad. If the device is a TLS client, it needs trusted root CA store (if server uses regular cert like for a browser) or a single CA cert (if the server uses corporate/internal CA). If device needs to authenticate using TLS client cert, it needs a unique cert and key inserted at manufacturing time. If device is a TLS server, it needs a unique cert and key inserted at manufacturing time. "At manufacturing time" can be replaced with provisioning at unboxing/setup time, or after device wipe, if needed.

Comment: OK, sorry for the migration. It is sometimes hard to guess if a question will fit.